# Sound Bug In kali linux

Tags: audio, hdmi, kali-linux

So, I switched to Kali recently my setup is a laptop with external display, mouse, keyboard, speaker trough HDMI display when I try to play something Kali always plays the sound on the HDMI channel (external speaker) even if I change it in setting only system sounds change to my headphones the only workaround I have found is to disable HDMI audio through pavucontrol what do I do to fix this

I also tried the Instructions on this website: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/406/how-to-enable-the-sound-on-kali-linux

Comment: See if this article helps you. ..... https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/406/how-to-enable-the-sound-on-kali-linux

Comment: that didnt work

Comment: Kali is not any kind of user system so it may not do what you want

Comment: I used kali before for years and wanted to see how arch so I replaced kali with arch for a while then I realized it was worse than kali (in my opinion) and switched back it's not like im a complete beginner to linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that reinstalling kali linux solved the problem.
the issue may have been created by me changing the audio output too fast